# How can I revoke OAuth access to Google (Cloud) Storage?

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-cloud-storage

I've been testing an app and granted it OAuth access via a token, however, I can't find anywhere in Google's Cloud Console to revoke its access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the [Revoke third-party access to your account information](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/41236?hl=en) instructions. The authorization is tied to your account.